# Using qsub within crontab?

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to qsub a script within crontab. Within a crontab txt file, I tried:

```
    0 1 * * * qsub /script.sh
```

The error I get is "/bin/sh: qsub: command not found."
I've tried a bunch of similar iterations and looked around online without success. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Programs executed under `cron` run with a limited set of environment variables. In particular, since it doesn't read your shell startup files (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.cshrc`, whatever), it won't have your `$PATH` settings; `$PATH` is likely to be something simple like `/usr/bin:/bin`.

You can set the PATH for a single command like this:

```
0 1 * * * PATH=/directory/containing/qsub:/usr/bin:/bin qsub /script.sh
```

You can also set environment variables globally; such settings will apply to all commands executed from your `crontab`:

```
PATH=/directory/containing/qsub:/usr/bin:/bin

0 1 * * * qsub /script.sh
```

`man 5 crontab`, or see [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/), for more information on writing crontabs.

If you want to see just what the environment for a cron job looks like, you can *temporarily* add this line to your crontab:

```
* * * * * printenv > cron-env
```

Wait until the top of the next minute, then `cat ~/cron-env` -- and then remove that line from your crontab so it doesn't keep executing.

(Is your script really in the root directory? Why isn't it under your home directory?)

Comment: Thanks I got it to work using your suggestion. My qsub was in /usr/local/bin/. The command that worked for me was 0 1 * * * PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin qsub /scriptpath/script.sh. Also, my script was not stored in my root directory. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The method works for me is that I first source the sge.sh under /etc/profile.d/sge.sh

Then the crontab will get the correct environment variable and able to run the qsub under crontab.